# Balanced Payments Fatal Error in Errors

Tags: php, json, balanced-payments

I've recently implemented Balanced Payments.  I've updated my composer.json file and yet I get this error when running the PHP:

PHP message: PHP Fatal error:

> Uncaught exception 'Balanced\Errors\Error' in
>   /app/vendor/balanced/balanced/src/Balanced/Errors/Error.php:42"

I ran the following on the command line, and it says dependencies were all updated:

```
composer update
```

My composer.json looks like this:

```
{
 "require" : {
 "braintree/braintree_php" : "2.28.0",
 "balanced/balanced" : "1.*"
  }
}
```

My PHP is as follows:

```
<?php

  #BALANCED
 require(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');

  Httpful\Bootstrap::init();
  RESTful\Bootstrap::init();
  Balanced\Bootstrap::init();

   Balanced\Settings::$api_key = "ak-test-*************************";

  $amount = $_POST["amount"];
  $href = $_POST["href"];

 $bank_account = Balanced\BankAccount::get($href);
 $bank_account->credits->create(array(
     "amount" => $amount
   ));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API returned a response that threw a catchable Error. I suggest you wrap the code in a try/catch and determine what the API error was. A few quick common guesses, as it could be any number of things, `$amount` or `$href` is null, or `$amount` was not the amount expressed as an integer.

Also, you'll find logs accessible via the Balanced Dashboard to be very helpful as you integrate the Balanced API.